# Versatile software architecture/pattern for web applications

Tags: design-patterns, architecture

I'm currently gathering all the possible information to build a new web application core.

I have built many different CMS'es before, but they have always turned out to be too weak for my requirements and to expand them, it takes too much time. Basicly, I want to build this "new" core, which would allow me to easily extend it with modules/plugins, you name it.

I have read about MVC, but I think there should be other architectures/patterns which could be used.

Could you please name any other architectures or design patterns you have used in past or are sticking with at the moment, and why exactly this architecture/pattern?

Answers with comparissions between different architectures are much appreciatied!

Thanks in advance!

## EDIT:

With CMS (in my case), I meant a static built site, where when you want to extend it, you have to change too much of code. Basicly, no architecture or logic behind the system.

My requirements now are that I need a versatile architecture behind my core. Core should be there only to make everything work together, not do stuff like content managing or anything, that's what modules are meant for. MVC really looks like the choice, but I'm interested in other architectures too.

I've imagined, that core would only take user requests. According to request, send them to appropriate module, but module again can request library or something, that should go through the core. Everything has to work with no extra use. If module doesn't need database, then there shouldn't be loaded library for database.
Simplified- everything has to work on demand. I know that it depends on me, but yeah, the question still is, **what architecture would bring the best results for this?**

Feel free to ask, I'm only 18 and not natively English, therefore it's hard to express myself.

Comment: What are you requirements?  A CMS is a very broad concept.

Comment: Take a look what do various open source CMSs offer and pickup some ideas.

Comment: I've seen lots of open source CMS'es, that's where I got my first steps in PHP. But now my knowledge has greatly increased and I want to build something from scratch. When I look at other peoples work, I kind of concentrate on it. With that I mean, that I cannot think "out of the box" then. I then think about how could I use the code, and cannot arrange changes to it. I basicly want something fresh, and I'm willing to learn a lot while doing it. Basicly, I would love textual ideas not working examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one the best architecture I've ever seen: http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracDev/ComponentArchitecture

Comment: +1 for pointing out this as it turned out to be a good read.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you do not know much about software architecture patterns, I would recommend you reading Pattern Oriented Software Architecture books and Enterprise Architecture Patterns.

What you describe somewhat resembles the idea of microkernel architecture pattern, try to look that up, you will definitely find it in the first of POSA books.

Comment: That's true, have never been interested in all that stuff. Only recently have started to take programming more seriously and so on. And thanks for recommendations, will sure look up those books!